# Casting a ref cursor into a table type in pl-sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I would like to cast a refcursor into a table type as shown below. The syntax below does not compile.The purpose is to get the results of a refcursor into a temporary table and then do some work on that table.

```
    create table vtest1 (a number, b number); 
    create table temptable1(a number, b number); 
    declare 
    pOUT SYS_REFCURSOR;
    type vtest1Tab is table of vtest1%rowtype;
    begin
      open pOUT for 'select * from vtest1';
      insert into temptable1(n1,n2)  
      select * from TABLE( cast(pOUT as vtest1Tab));
      close pOUT;
    end;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you need to use a Ref Cursor?  Are you sure you need to use a temporary table?  These are both features which are frequently misused by beginners when there are easier options, such as populating a PL/SQL collection with a normal query, or even a dynamic one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bulk collect` and `forall` instead of `insert into ... select`:

```
create table vtest1 (a number, b number);

insert into vtest1 values (1,2);

create table temptable1(a number, b number);

declare 
  pOUT SYS_REFCURSOR;
  type vtest1Tab is table of vtest1%rowtype;
  v_t vtest1Tab;
begin
  open pOUT for 'select * from vtest1';
  fetch pOUT bulk collect into v_t;
  close pOUT;
  forall indx in v_t.first..v_t.last
   insert into temptable1
     values v_t(indx)
    ;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the names of your tables at compile-time, I don't understand the point of using the REF Cursor?  Why not just have your anonymous block as:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO temptable1 SELECT * FROM vtest1;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

GWU's answer certainly works if you really want the flexibility of passing the source table name as a string.